# Multiple Subscribers to event source observable - async pipe keeps subscribing and unsubscribing

Tags: angular

Bit of a headscratcher for me:

basically I am implementing a simple angular app to display and reassign names to ids.

```
 export class Assignment {
   name: string;
   id?: string;
 }
```

for this the backend publishes the endpoints:

```
GET /assignments
> [{"1": "id-a"},{"2": ""}] // where "2" is unassigned

PUT /assignments/:name/:id

GET /stream
> text/event-stream of new assignments as type="update", data = {"name": "1", "id":"id-a"} ...
```

The frontend has a service that exposes all these endpoints, with the stream one set up like this:

```
export class HttpService {
  private source: EventSource;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.source = new EventSource('/stream');
  }
  ...
   public getStream(): Observable<Assignment> {
    return  new Observable(observer => {
      console.log('subscribed to stream');
      this.source.addEventListener('update',(evt: MessageEvent) => 
          this.zone.run(() => observer.next(JSON.parse(evt.data))));
      this.source.onerror = evt => observer.error(evt);
      return () => { console.log('unsubscribing'); }
    });
  }
}
```

I created a component to hold one assignment quite simple

```
template: `<div> {{assignment.name}} = {{assignment.id}} <div>`
@Input() assignment: Assignment
```

Now comes the catch, my app component is set up like this:

template:

```
 <app-assignment *ngFor="let item of assignments" [assignment]="getUpdatesForName(item) | async"></app-assignment >
```

component:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  public selected: string;
  public assignments: Assignment[];
  public update$: Observable<Assignment>;

  constructor(private httpservice: HttpService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpservice.getAssignments().subscribe( it => this.assignments = it);
    this.update$ = this.httpservice.getStream();
  }

  public selectSound(soundid: string) {
    this.selected = soundid;
  }


  public getUpdatesForName(assignment: Assignment): Observable<Assignment> {
    return concat(
      of( assignment ),
      this.update$.pipe(
        filter(it => it.name=== assignment.name)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that the moment I change an assignment via the rest API no update ever hits the UI. 
Instead the log steadily fills up with the 'subscribed' and 'unsubscribed' messages.
So it seems the async pipe is subscribing and unsubscribing over and over again and never gets anything done.

My first assumption was, that always adding new listeners to the source would clog up something, so I tried holding an array of subscribers and just one message listener

```
   export class HttpService {
      private source: EventSource;
      private subscribers :Subscriber<Assignment>[] = [];

      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private zone: NgZone) {
        this.source = new EventSource('/stream');
        this.source.addEventListener('update',(evt: MessageEvent) => this.zone.run(() => this.subscribers.forEach(it => it.next(JSON.parse(evt.data)), false)));
        this.source.onerror = evt => console.log('error in stream' + evt)
      }
    ...
     public getStream(): Observable<Assignment> {
        return  new Observable(observer => {
          console.log('subscribed to stream');
          this.subscribers.push(observer)
          return () => {
           this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(it => it !== observer)
          };
        });
      }
```

which didn't change anything.

The whole thing works as expected when I replace the async pipe with passing in the Observable and doing a `subscribe(input => localmember = input)` in `OnInit` of the child component

EDIT:

I did some tests and found, that using a replay subject makes it work for exactly the number of messages that fit the replay buffer.

So I assume the async pipe resubscribes each time a CD cycle happens and unsubs at the end of it? But how would it know when a new item gets emitted when it unsubscribes at the end of CD?

Answer (score 1):

ok I got it, but I can see someone having this issue and did not want to just delete my question.

basically, thanks to https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2019/10/14/angulars-async-pipe-intricacies/

where it says:

> While not the main focus of this article, another important note here
>   is that the async pipe will only return the value retrieved from the
>   Promise if the input is still the exact same Promise instance. If
>   you’re calling an async method, or a method that creates a new Promise
>   every time it’s called, the async pipe will assume that any value it
>   has is no longer relevant and thus will likely never produce a usable
>   value.

SO the way I set it up, on CD, angular would re evaluate the input for the child component `[assignment]="getUpdatesForName(item) | async"`.

This, because of the filter I want to pipe it through will always return a new Observable, causing the constant sub-unsub pattern, and never resulting in a usable value.

The solution was to create all the filtered Observables once and store them to a Map>.